Question on join varieties from Hulek's algebraic geometry.
"Let $X, Y \subset \mathbb{C}^4$ be varieties defined by
$$
X := \{ (t,t^2,t^3,0) \,|\, t \in \mathbb{C} \}, \quad
Y := \{ (0, u, 0, 1) \,|\, u \in \mathbb{C} \}.
$$
The join variety of $X$ and $Y$ is the set
$$
J(X,Y) := \bigcup_{P\in X, Q\in Y} 
\overline{PQ} \subset \mathbb{C}^4,
$$
where $\overline{PQ}$ is the line through $P$ and $Q$.
Describe the set $J(X,Y)$.
Is $J(X,Y)$ an affine (or quasi-affine) variety?"
Note: This question has been  asked on MSE before but does not have an answer and I am still unable to progress.
I have constructed the lines in $J(X,Y)$ by introducing a variable $s,$ giving me the following system of equations
$$\begin{align*} x &= (1-s)t \\ y &= (1-s)t^2 +su \\ z &= (1-s)t^3 \\ s &= w .\end{align*}$$ This describes a mapping, call it $\varphi,$ from $\mathbb{A}^3_{(t,u,s)}$ to $\mathbb{A}^4_{(x,y,z,w)}.$
How can I show that the image of $\varphi$ is a closed (or complement of a closed) subset of $\mathbb{A}^4_{(x,y,z,w)}?$ I suspect I will get a hypersurface, so how can I express $\mathrm{im}(\varphi)$ as the vanishing locus of a single polynomial?
